# printer automatically stop in the last row

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have problem to print data window, I want to print in the last row printer automatically stop.

Row in data window more 1, depend on input data.

Comment: I do not understand the question,

Comment: I mean, printer automatic stop in the last row. may be like as struck / bill  in cafe or restaurant. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do what you want with PrintDataWindow, which is used with the PrintOpen and PrintClose commands. See the help for PrintDataWindow for the details.